# Wordpress-Contac tform7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

i have problem with my wordpress contact form7, i am not getting any mail form my website when the user submit a form.i am using many forms in my contact form 7, i tried all the way,(it not working any mail server ie.smtp and php mailer) even i am not getting any response contact form while submit the form (ie. success or failed etc) just got the alert message (details sent successfully), i am checked my wordpress can sent a mail (ie . forgot password mail). i have to fix this issue quickly so pls some one help me to resolve (i updated all ie.wordpress and contact form) my wesite link is : http://www.maldentrans.com/contact-us

Comment: can you provide few images of your Cf7 config

Comment: Did you checked in spam folder

Comment: yes, your contact form is working using inspect element you can check it..check your  spam folder.

Answer (score 0):

One of the things that prevent the Contact Form 7 from working correctly is the email you use with the form. 
The general idea is that if you use one of the e-mail addresses from the public email services like Gmail or Yahoo they will be blocked and the form won't work. That happens due to numerous anti spam restrictions.

So if switch from the Form to the Mail panel in the Form settings make sure to use the email domain that matches your website. In your case this could be something like info@maldentrans.com.

Make sure to use that email in the following fields: To and From.

After you set it up - everything should work fine!